# How to post images on Google Plus in iOS Application?

Tags: ios, objective-c, oauth-2.0

1. I have tried to share an image on Google Plus using OAuth 2.0. Is it possible to share images on Google+ via OAuth 2.0?
2. Also I have used Google Plus share URL (https://plus.google.com/share?url=).
   Can we share images using this URL?

Please let me know if anyone has posted an image using any of the above mentioned points.

**Note:** I don't want to use Google API because my application is rejected by Apple.

> **Reason:** “The app launches mobile Safari to complete signing into Google+ before returning to the app. However, the use should not have
>   to exit the app to use it. To resolve the issue, it would be
>   appropriate to revise your app to allow the user to log through the
>   app, to create another authentication method for your app, or to
>   remove this requirement from using your app”

So I choose OAuth 2.0 and Google share URL but I am not able to share images on Google+.